# Why is it acceptable to expect that Flash will be available/enabled, but not JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, html

It doesn't take long when surfing the web to observe the general consensus that Flash is an expected standard, that it's okay to say "If you don't have Flash, my website won't work." Yet in the same regard, JavaScript is expected to degrade peacefully if the user does not have it enabled.

I personally favor the "HTML5" approach, in opposition to Flash, due to the poor performance Flash brings to Mac OS X and Linux

The overall outlook of the Flash way vs. the JavaScript way seems like the biggest challenge to me in [Steve Job's prediction of HTML5 overtaking Flash](http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2010/01/googles-dont-be-evil-mantra-is-bullshit-adobe-is-lazy-apples-steve-jobs/), and I personally haven't seen any sign of change.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Who says it's okay? I certainly don't think it is.

Comment: It's usually called "gracefully", but I like "peacefully". :D

Comment: @deceze: Yeah I like peacefully better as well.

Comment: Rather interesting coming back to this question 2 years on. Mobile Flash is no longer developed for Android. Apple never capitulated, and Flash has lost its one great advantage, ubiquity. Any site that requires Flash now will likely no longer be functional for the majority in 3 to 5 years time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about almost entirely different groups of people with very different worldviews. That's why they say two different things. Very few people are both gung-ho Flash fanatics *and* slavish adherents to progressive enhancement.

For the people who support Javascript, one of the big reasons many do so is that it's an open standard with free implementations that is accessible to anybody, not just those favored by Adobe. This feeling that Web content should be available to everybody on the Web also makes them hostile to Javascript that takes the same "My way or the highway" stance that led them to reject Flash.

Comment: Which is what confuses me. I'm not seeing amateur products made in Flash, which is leading me to believe there are programmers out there that either know nothing but Flash or have tunnel vision for web standards

Comment: Maybe because amateurs don't like to fork out $179 for flash?

Comment: @Andrew Dunn - FYI the Flex compiler is open source and so is the IDE FlashDevelop. The Adobe Flash IDE is aimed at animators and yes you have to pay for that.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 will probably not kill Flash. Although I'm an Actionscript 3 developer, I have little love for Adobe and if anyone is going to kill Flash, I believe it will be Adobe themselves by failing to adapt.

Web standards are great but inevitably changes take for ever.Solutions developed by smaller entities can implement changes and adapt faster. Look at how JQuery changed the perception of Javascript. Most people have already forgotten that until recently there was very little love for Javascript, which is probably where the degrade gracefully attitude comes from.

The consensus is now to complain about Flash , the real shame is what Adobe has done with it , or more to the point hasn't done to improve it. I agree with Steve Jobs on that one, Adobe are either lazy or misguided. In any case totally inefficient.

In my view there's nothing wrong with a plugin, provided it works as expected and with a penetration above 90% , Flash has/had the potential to become a standard itself... in another world that is.

Comment: I am on the fence as to whether Adobe is lazy. I mean on the one hand it has taken individuals like Joa Ebert and Nicolas Cannasse to optimize Flash and create great tools. Yet on the other hand Adobe have a unique set of mission goals that tie their hands. At least they have now released a 64bit player, rumored to be releasing full GPU support, and have created the Open Screen initiative.

Comment: Admittedly an exaggeration out of frustration of seeing people bending over backwards to try and achieve what Flash does without Flash. Considering its current market penetration , Flash is in a unique position. If the future is with web apps, I'd rather code with AS3 than Javascript, although I'm absolutely ready to learn another language if it's faster & renders more efficiently. 64bit yes, at last , only beta though , 2011 is soon enough but couldn't have they done it earlier?

Comment: Yes I agree. Adobe appears to be reactive rather than proactive. One wonders what the results would be if under better leadership. It is a shame because I fully agree that I would rather code with AS3 than JavaScript, it's just that much more enjoyable. But like you I am seeking the best performance and wouldn't hesitate to learn something new if it is reliable, offers better performance, and uses a decent language. I am hoping that they announce full GPU support for the next Flash player at the upcoming Adobe Max otherwise I will definitely think about learning WebGL.

Comment: So it does. Didn't realize it used a Java like syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not OK to say either of those, in the general case. However for some it's acceptable to give up on having a working site for some percentage of users.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the kind of project you are developing for.

It's only safe to assume the user will be able do interact only with the HTML (that's why it's a good idea to hijax your form instead of assuming the user will be able to run your ajax function)

As for FLASH I aways assume it will be unavailable to a small be considerable group of users (iphone, and ipad user won't be able to interact with your flash)

So basically, when developing a portal I assume that:

1. The user browser will be able to
   display HTML
2. There's a great probability that the user's browser will be able to interpret javascript
3. There's a considerably smaller probability that the user will have the flash plugin

My rule of thumb is: If you have to have flash at all use it for non-important stuff. All important stuff should be able to work fine with just HTML

Comment: I would say the opposite: If you're going to use Flash, use it for something that Flash is uniquely suited to. Video capture, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because Flash has a penetration of around 99% of all internet connected computers, and acts exactly the same across the board. Flash has many features which are not replaceable (until very recently, thanks to HTML5 and better JavaScript implementations) While JavaScript implementations are all incomplete as well as varying in between browsers.

I'm not a flash developer, but I'm guessing there would be different methodologies too. The whole mantra of modern web development is a sort of additive synthesis, so you start with something basic, then work up from there, building up features as you go along.

The real reason is that if you use flash on your website, you probably don't give a toss about things like accessibility and other minor concerns.

JavaScript developers are also **much** nicer people.

Comment: I'd argue the penetration for Flash, given the popularity of the iPad http://paidcontent.org/article/419-best-buy-ceo-ipad-cannibalizing-up-to-50-percent-of-laptop-sales/ and the online-shopping revenue generated by the mobile market.

Comment: I keep hearing that, but I don't see it as its popularity doesn't seem to be decreasing, despite Google/Apple seeming to dislike it.

Comment: Google doesn't dislike it, they recently embeded it into Chrome. The only person who hates Flash is Steve Job's and his loyal minions. Sure it can be annoying, but so can 99% of the rest of the stuff on teh internets.

Comment: @MooGoo - it's amusing how in Steve's open letter that he was super critical of Flash being ported to native apps, yet now his tune has changed. What does that say about his credibility lol. @Andrew Dunn - Flash people are pretty nice too. See I could have taken offense at your comment but didn't, that proves it ;-)

Comment: His tune changed because the FCC made him change it :P

Comment: @MooGoo: Steve Jobs' "loyal minions" hate Flash because Adobe allowed the Mac version to languish in a practically unusable state for years and it was responsible for more lockups and crashes than almost anything else on the Mac platform. It's kind of a valid reason.

Answer (score 0):

Typically JavaScript is used to support basic but important operations, and being important goes hand in hand with high usage frequency, large audience, possibly business critical. Thus it is important that they require "peaceful degradation".

Flash tends to be used for splashy stuff, like games, heavy UI apps (like paint style programs). These tend to be less important and so less reason for them to degrade peacefully.

For example, I can see the Flash part of Google's analytics site making way for HTML5 in the future. It is suited to it. But something like Google's street view I see no real reason to go down the HTML5 route for it (although I suspect they still might).